# API Call from SQL Server using SQL Service Broker

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a table with some fields. On update, I want to trigger an api call to an url from SQL Server. I have tried with **SQL CLR**. But I want to do this with **SQL Service Broker**. Is this a right method to do this?

Is there any other method to do this?

Comment: IMO you need to do a little more research and see what is/is not possible. https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+Service+Broker+trigger